# "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/proxy/HibernateProxy" in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, eclipse-plugin

I have a plugin-based Eclipse app where I put my persistent data in X plugin, and the hibernate-database service in Y plugin.

*The persistent classes are in X, and the HibernateUtil, Dao, all the hibernate-related jars and the hbm.xml mapping files for the persistent classes are in Y.*

When I run the app, I see lots of exceptions like:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException
javassist.CannotCompileException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
org.hibernate.HibernateException
```

All of them end with "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/proxy/HibernateProxy"

If I work with a database on my localhost, these exceptions don't affect my app.
But when I try to connect to a remote database, my nested HQL queries don't work. I'm guessing that this has something to do with the proxies.

Is there a way to get rid of this problem without merging X and Y plugins into a single plugin?

Comment: I suppose that you want the two plugins to work independently from each other, right? If that is the case, you should make sure that both plugins can operate without the other, i.e. jar dependencies are declared independently for each plugin.

Comment: The jar dependencies are independent for each plugin. But Y plugin is dependent on X. Because it needs the persistent classes provided by X.

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't most probably due to the loading mechanism of eclipse plugins. There's a fix for that - the buddy loading.

In the MANIFEST.MF file of the Hibernate plugin (which NEEDS the buddy loading), such as org.hibernate.eclipse, add a line:

```
Eclipse-BuddyPolicy:registered
```

and in the MANIFEST.MF file of your plugin project or RCP project, add the line:

```
Eclipse-RegisterBuddy:org.hibernate.eclipse
```

This should resolve the issue.

Here's a blog post around this problem:

http://hwellmann.blogspot.de/2008/11/hibernate-and-osgi-pragmatic-solution.html

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but unfortunately this approach is not suitable with my osgi modularity. What I mean is, org.hibernate.eclipse is generic and must not be dependent on anything in my system.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate supporting libraries were missed in your remote deployment.

create a `lib` folder under WEB-INF and copy all the supporting jar files to this lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

This solves the problem:

In X plugin,
Eclipse-BuddyPolicy: registered

In Y plugin,
Require-Bundle: (x plugin id)
Eclipse-RegisterBuddy: (x plugin id)

Answer (score 0):

At its root, this is a classic [OSGi ClassLoader issue.](http://blog.osgi.org/2011/05/what-you-should-know-about-class.html) The solution depends on the version of Hibernate you are using.

### Hibernate 4.X

You must set the [ProxyFactory classLoaderProvider](https://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/html/javassist/util/proxy/ProxyFactory.html#classLoaderProvider) to provide a class loader that includes

1. Your entity classes
2. Hibernate Proxy (org.hibernate.proxy)
3. Javassist proxy (javassist.util.proxy)

### Hibernate 5.X

Hibernate now uses the classloader of the entity class in the proxy factory. You must include Hibernate proxy (org.hibernate.proxy) and Javassist (javassist.util.proxy) in the Import-Package section of the OSGi Manifest **of the bundle(s) that contains the entity classes** [3](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/753293), which may be different from the bundle that creates the EntityManagerFactory.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exception running an Arquillian Test.
In my case i forgot to add persistence.xml to the archive:

```
archive.addAsResource("META-INF/persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml");
```